# Android SharedActionProvider without displaying latest used action

Tags: android

By default Android `SharedActionProvider` shows last used action(facebook, twitter etc..). How do I disable not to show recent used action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to customize this, so you can't disable it.